# How do I copy rows from other sheets to the target sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a situation and I really admire if you could help me, I've browsed every solution to the questions posted on SOF that merely related to my problem but still I couldn't find a way around it!

I have a master sheet with column names a to z (for example), also I have numerous other sheets with dissimilar names, that have the same column pattern, now I want a code that copies rows from other sheets which start from row 2 in every sheet, to the next empty row in master sheet. Also the thing is every sheet has a variable amount of rows that cannot be specified.
I really admire if you could help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`For Each` is your friend - you can loop all `Worksheets` and all rows and just point the row in the non-master sheet to the last row of the master sheet.

```
Sub ConsolidateWorksheets(ByVal MasterSheet As Worksheet)
    MasterLastRow = MasterSheet.Range("A" & MasterSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    For Each DataSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        LastRow = DataSheet.Range("A" & DataSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If DataSheet.Name <> MasterSheet.Name Then
            For Each DataRow In DataSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)
                MasterSheet.Range("A" & MasterLastRow & ":Z" & MasterLastRow).Value = DataSheet.Range("A" & DataRow.Row & ":Z" & DataRow.Row).Value
                MasterLastRow = MasterLastRow + 1
            Next DataRow
        End If
    Next DataSheet
End Sub

Sub Launcher()
    Set MasterSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' Comment this row after testing
    ' Set MasterSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("YourWorksheetNameHere") ' Uncomment this row after testing and update the name of your Master Sheet

    ConsolidateWorksheets MasterSheet

End Sub
```

> You can run this code by running the `Sub Launcher()`

Answer (score -2):

```
sub test()
  dim MainSheetusedrows,OtherSheetusedrows as integer
  dim noOfSheets as integer

  noOfSheets = Thisworkbook.Sheets.Count

  for i = 1 to noOsfSheets
     sheets(i).activate
     OtherSheetusedrows = sheets(i).Range("A"& activesheet.rows.count).end(xlup).row
     sheets(i).Range("A2:Z"& OtherSheetusedrows).copy
     Sheets("MainSheet").activate
     MainSheetusedrows=Sheets("MainSheet")._
                      Range("A" & activesheet.rows.count).end(xlup).row
     Sheets("MainSheet").Range("A" & MainSheetusedrows + 1).select
     Activesheet.paste
  next
end sub
```

This code will loop through all the sheets and from "OtherSheetusedrows" and gets the number of rows in each sheet and copies the used data to the main sheet.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I run the code and nothing happens. I have uploaded the file I used the code on in the address below. And I notice you've set the range in line 10 as Range("A2:Z"&... My file may not necessarily end columns in "Z" so is there any way to write the code to get around it?                      http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=95995556374853967699

Comment: You can edit the code from "z" to whichever the column you need. you have to edit the above code according to your requirements E.g : "Thisworkbook" refers to the workbook which via is coded

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on how to edit the range, but the thing is the code does not do anything when I run it.

Comment: It's not a best practice to use Activate and ActiveSheet. It would be better to take a `Worksheet` as an input variable and then loop `for Sheet in Sheets` while not copying data from the supplied master `Worksheet`